# System.out.println() messages in JBoss AS

Tags: jboss7.x

Is there a straight forward approach for JBoss AS to print messages to the console in eclipse? I intend to use them only for debugging purposes and nothing more (I swear).

I'm new to JBoss and I don't know where to start and what to do to get my System.out.println()-messages appear in the console.

Unfortunately I have been struggling too long for today to achieve this rather natural requirement. I'm using JBoss AS 7.1.

edit:

Ok, looks like this time the problem is sitting in front of the screen. I couldn't find my logging even in the server.log. The reason is that the code which I was executing throwed an error which prevented the sysouts from being printed to the console. I'm sorry. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make a `Sysout` in your application, you can find it at the `server.log`, inside the folder `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/log`

That, however, is not the best practice, since there's a lot of configuration and possibility at the log. You can check more information about that [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Logging+Configuration)

But, if you just say `System.out.println('hello world')` it will be out at `server.log`

All logging after the boot is made there so there you can check your `System.out.println()` stuff

Comment: I just wonder, when we normally sysout anything , it prints it at the eclipse console but when our application is deployed on Jboss then sysout prints the value at Server console and server logs. What is it, that makes this change?

Comment: I would like to know how to make it possible to see the output of `System.out.println()` in the console of Eclipse.

Comment: @Gab You have to run JBoss inside eclipse, like James said in the other answer. This way every log will appears at the console tab on Eclipse

Answer (score 2):

With a default install a console handler and a file handler are configured. If you want to log to either you just need to use a logger. Printing to `System.out` or `System.err` it will work as well, but I would suggest using a logging facade like JBoss Logging, SLF4J or even just J.U.L.

If you're wanting to run JBoss AS inside eclipse the easiest way is to use [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools). You can start, stop and deploy your application from within eclipse locally for testing.

Answer (score 1):

In my project I had 2 log4j.proprties files one is provided by jboss other is in my workspace. I removed one log4j.properties file now I am able to see sysout on the console.